# How to better handle hide(), show() divs between multiple menu items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I have these menu items.

```
A    B    C    D
```

And the jQuery to show/hide their respective target wrapper div's.

```
$("#showItemA").click(function () {

        $("#aWrapper").show();
        $("#bWrapper").hide();
        $("#cWrapper").hide();
        $("#dWrapper").hide();
}
```

It's getting messy and hard to keep track of.  Is there a better way to **condense** this to only 1-2 functions?

Anchor links:

```
<a id="showItemA">A</a>
<a id="showItemB">B</a>
<a id="showItemC">C</a>
<a id="showItemD">D</a>
```

DIV Wrappers

```
<div id="aWrapper"></div>
<div id="bWrapper"></div>
<div id="cWrapper"></div>
<div id="dWrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Y dont you use class names or you can make a variable equal `$("#aWrapper");` for example `var wrapper1 = $("#aWrapper");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

Anchor links:

```
  <a id="aWrapper" class="myMenu">A</a>
  <a id="bWrapper" class="myMenu">B</a>
```

Div wrapper

```
 <div class="aWrapper myWrapper"></div>
 <div class="bWrapper myWrapper"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".myMenu").click(function () {
    $(".myWrapper").hide();
    $("." + this.id).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. First, figure out a selector that will select all menu wrappers and hide them all. Then show the one you want.

```
$("#showItemA").click(function () {

        $(".menuWrapper").hide();
        $("#aWrapper").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your markup,

```
$('div[id*="Wrapper"]').hide();
$('a[id*="showItem"]').on('click', function() {
    $('div[id*="Wrapper"]').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).html().toLowerCase()+"Wrapper").show();
})​​​​​​​;​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MfhPc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HTML5 data-* attributes** to get the work done..

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="showItemA" data-id="aWrapper">A</a>
<a href="#" id="showItemB" data-id="bWrapper">B</a>
<a href="#" id="showItemC" data-id="cWrapper">C</a>
<a href="#" id="showItemD" data-id="dWrapper">D</a>
DIV Wrappers

<div id="aWrapper">A</div>
<div id="bWrapper">B</div>
<div id="cWrapper">C</div>
<div id="dWrapper">D</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('a[data-id]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('div').hide();
    $('#'+ id).show()
});​
```

**[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/kz2m2/)**

Comment: Big fan of data-* attributes.